# How to Use Where Query Builder in Laravel>

Tags: php, laravel

I've a Laravel Application but being more straight forward!
How to use where query, i want to get all the data of table where email is current `auth()->user()->email`.

I've used a submitter column where i post the email of who is posting the data.
Currently i'm trying like this:

```
@foreach (\App\Models\InsertFormModel::all()->where('submitter', value: strtolower(auth()->user()->email)) as $formData)
```

Comment: You need to read the Laravel documentation or watch tutorials about Laravel first. Also, have little knowledge of what the MVC pattern is. You are trying to execute the query in view which is not wrong but not a standard practice.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that in view? i need asap help

Comment: `->all()`  will get ... all entries. Use `->get()` or `->first()`

Answer (score 0):

**I think it's enough like this**

```
$email = strtolower( auth()->user()->email );
$get_data = \App\Models\InsertFormModel::where('submitter',$email)->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correct it seems you are trying to using `where` clause on `Collection` (which also has a method called [where](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-where) but for filter data on its items) because `all()` method will fetch all records in your table in database and put into a Collection object. You could try this

```
@foreach (\App\Models\InsertFormModel::where(('submitter', strtolower(auth()->user()->email))->get() as $formData)
```